# How SQL do in like?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like do multiple like in query, the logic like below.

E.g:
Table1:

```
ID
AA001BB
AA002BB
AA003CC
AA004CC
AA004DD
AA006DD
```

Table2

```
ID
001
002
004
```

SQL Query Logic like:

```sql
select * from table1 where ID likein (select '%'+ID+'%' from table2)
```

Get result:

```
ID
AA001BB
AA002BB
AA004CC
AA004DD
```

Comment: use `EXISTS()` in `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Squirrel mention in comment, you can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.id LIKE ('%' + t2.id + '%'))
```

here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1dca8e97dc09a4c8032ae58fc1f16336) for better examine.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Like operator on ON Clause** :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE( ID VARCHAR(500))
Insert Into @T VALUES
('AA001BB')
,('AA002BB')
,('AA003CC')
,('AA004CC')
,('AA004DD' )
,('AA006DD' )


DECLARE @T1 TABLE( ID VARCHAR(500))
Insert Into @T1 VALUES 
('001'),
('002'),
('004')


SELECT * FROM @T T
INNER JOIN @T1 T1 ON T.ID LIKE CONCAT('%',T1.ID,'%')
```